# Which part do I have to change to make splint interpolation?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, interpolation

I am studying about the Scipy and try to make interpolations.

Now there is a problem in making a splint interpolation and I can't find which part do I have to change, even reading a webpage of scipy.interpolate

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y = np.array([1., 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2])

f_lin = interpolate.interp1d(x,y)
x_new = np.arange(1, 5, 0.1)
y_lin = f_lin(x_new)

tck = interpolate.splrep(x, y, s=0)
y_spl = interpolate.splev(x_new, tck, der=0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, "o", label="Data")
ax.plot(x_new,y_new,label="Linear")
ax.plot(x_new,y_spl,label="Spline")
ax.legend()
```

When I print output of this code, I just get a linear interpolate without splint interpoltaion.

Comment: Your x and y values are linearly dependent. You'll need to change at least one of the values to get away from a line.

Comment: I mark in spots of value with the plot and can clasify with the point, line and spline if it is worked correctly. 
Actually, It is worked with plot and linear interpolate.